Background Image Not Rendering in Next.js 14 Component
I’m having trouble with rendering a background image in my Next.js 14 project. The URL for the image is correctly generated, but when I view the blog’s main page, the background image doesn’t appear—it’s just a black background with the text over it.
Below is the relevant part of my code:
import { simpleBlogCard } from "@/lib/interface";
import { client, urlFor } from "@/lib/sanity";
import Image from "next/image";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";

async function getData() {
  const query = `
    *[_type == 'blog'] | order(_createdAt desc) {
      title,
      "currentSlug": slug.current,
      excerpt,
      blogImage
    }`;

  const data = await client.fetch(query);

  return data;
}

export default async function page() {
  const data: simpleBlogCard[] = await getData();

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 mt-5 gap-5">
      {data.map((post) => (
        <div className="max-w-xs w-full group/card" key={post.currentSlug}>
          <div
            className={cn(
              "cursor-pointer overflow-hidden relative card h-96 rounded-md shadow-xl max-w-sm mx-auto backgroundImage flex flex-col justify-between p-4",
              `bg-[url(${urlFor(post.blogImage).url()})] bg-cover`
            )}
          >
            <div className="absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 transition duration-300 group-hover/card:bg-black opacity-60"></div>
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-4 z-10">
              <Image
                height="100"
                width="100"
                alt="Avatar"
                src="/aldo.jpg"
                className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full border-2 object-cover"
              />
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <p className="font-normal text-base text-gray-50 relative z-10">
                  Aldo
                </p>
                <p className="text-sm text-gray-400">2 min read</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="text content">
              <h1 className="font-bold text-xl md:text-2xl text-gray-50 relative z-10">
                {post.title}
              </h1>
              <p className="font-normal text-sm text-gray-50 relative z-10 my-4">
                {post.excerpt}
              </p>
              <a
                href={`/blog/${post.currentSlug}`}
                className="text-primary mt-4 relative z-10"
              >
                Read More
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

Appreciate any response.
Rendered in the browser

tailwind is a post css, so you have to store background url in a css variable and then assign the variable to background.
